# Python select COM-port

Tags: python

Win10, Python application that communicates with National Instruments USB-6210 and a COM-port.
It does flashing, measuring, and settings on a µC-unit.

The program has a window, a few buttons and such.

I would like to be able to specify which:
Path to the STM32_cube_CLI.exe. Already done.
Path to the HEX-file to program into the µC. Already done.
COM-port to use. This causes trouble.

I can list the COM-ports, no problem.
I use a tk.menubar and what I see could be an OptionMenu that activates when I click on the menubar->Select COM Port.

But so far - having tried a LOT - to no avail.

The selection-menu (OptionMenu?) needs to "pop-up" when needed and invisible otherwise.

Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You question is flagged as python but you seem to have a complete workflow between your device and a dedicated software (exe). What do you want to achieve? Replace the exe by a python program?

Comment: It's the OptionBox I really want to show on the "canvas" when I click the file-menu->Select COM-port, do the selection and kill the OptionBox.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then update your post accordingly. You provided a lot of details that are useless without a clear context. Try to rephrase your problem in a gradual way. Remember we are not in front of your screen.